# Canadian Visa: VFS vs Embassy

Tags: visas, canada

I am applying for a Canadian visa from Munich. It is now mandatory to provide biometrics at a Visa Application Centre when you apply for a visitor visa. There is no consulate in Munich and I can either go to VFS in Berlin or the Canadian embassy in Vienna.

I can find the information on VFS website that they provide a return passport delivery service but I cannot find similar information on the Canadian embassy, Vienna website. Do I need to go again in person to collect my passport after the visa is processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canadian embassy in Austria is located in Vienna, and its webpage is [here](https://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/austria-autriche/contact-contactez.aspx?lang=eng).

I wondered if you'd tried asking your question of them. The embassy's page contains a link ["Our Office > Contact Us."](https://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/austria-autriche/contact-contactez.aspx?lang=eng) I clicked on the link, which took me to [the embassy's contact page](https://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/austria-autriche/contact-contactez.aspx?lang=eng).

In the center, the contact page contains this text:

> Visa and Immigration section is no longer open for submission of applications, documents or passports, or any enquiries.

Thus, you'll have to apply using VFS in Berlin.

Comment: Well, I tried contacting the consulate in Munich and they asked me to apply from embassy in Vienna, Austria. I also contacted the Canadian embassy in Vienna, but I have not received their response up until now.

Comment: The Canadians might be transitioning from using Embassy and Consulate staff to process visa applications, to using VFS for doing so. In any event, because the Vienna embassy clearly directs to you VFS, you should apply at VFS.

Answer (score 0):

The IRCC website still states that it is possible to submit applications in Vienna but that's not true as stated in the above answer. I received a reply from the Canadian embassy in Vienna:

> Please be informed that our Embassy is not open for the in-person or postal/courier submission or pick-up of passports and that you must use one of the Visa Application Centres (VAC) located within our territory to transmit your passport to our Embassy. Please refer to the instructions regarding the passport submission and return on the following website:
>   https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account/where-submit-passport.html

For detailed information regarding the VAC services, please contact the VAC directly.